# Connect and develop with sharepoint server 2013

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I recently setup a sharepoint server 2013 on our company and have found really good examples how you can override the suitbar with custom links.
Now that I'm trying to implement those examples i get to that point where Visual Studio 2012 and Office development tools is installed.
When i choose to start a new project I select New Project > Templates > Visual C# > Office/SharePoint > SharePoint Solutions > SharePoint 2013 Empty Project hit ok and i get an error that says Sharepoint not installed?
Am I supposed to install VS 2012 and develop om my Sharepoint 2013 server directly?

Comment: "The difference between a SharePoint developer and any other kind of developer is that the SharePoint developer thinks it's normal to develop on the server", _anon_.

Comment: ... because without the SharePoint binaries there is no development. CI with automatic builds got a lot better with 2012, but we are a long way from "other" kind of development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very common way to develop SharePoint applications is to run a virtual machine ([hyper-v under windows 8 for example](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36188)) on your development workstation.

You can also [dual-boot into a vhd file](http://garvis.ca/2012/06/20/boot-from-vhd/).

You can also install Windows Server 2012 and use one of the many [desktop conversion techniques to use it as your primary operating system on your workstation](http://www.win2012workstation.com/).

Another often seen technique is to have a virtual machine hosted in the cloud or a datacenter, running both SharePoint Server and Visual Studio. Then connect to that machine using Remote Desktop.

With some trickery, you could have the SharePoint 2010 installer install om a workstation OS. [This no longer works on SharePoint 2013.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/54292) The reason this support was removed is due to the inclusion of Boot from VHD and Hyper-v into Windows 8.

It is my experience that if you just want to build your application and not run or debug it, [that just having the assemblies copied over from an actual SharePoint Server will allow you to do that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx). I haven't found an updated document for SharePoint 2013 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to develop on the sharepoint server directly using Visual Studio as Sharepoint server GAC has the required server object models to work programatically with [sharepoint server object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164060.aspx#ServerOM).

You can aslo develop on client machine using [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164060.aspx#ClientManagedOM) or [WCF Data Services Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164060.aspx#WCFDataServices).

Comment: Wow! I did read it on Microsoft but I thought it was a typo or maybe for another unique case... But jaiks, all those examples and everyone of them development on the server!